# Daphne multi process exit working when running with supervisord. Set 4 process but only 1 keeps running

Tags: django, supervisord, django-channels, daphne

I've Daphne working with Supervisord.

1. Config is set to have **4 simultaneous processes** but it happens 3 of them exit without explanation and only one keeps running properly.
2. I do have **2 CPUs**.

Supervisord config is:
[image]

The output is:
[image]

Then I tried changing the File descriptor:
[image]

The output still show only one process
[image]
[image]

Then I tried some variations:
1 - Change the file descriptor to --fd 10
2 - Replace --fd 10 with --endpoint fd:fileno=0

Same luck... or lack of luck.

Am I missing something? Why I just can't have 4th processes running all time? Does it make a difference in performance between 1 and 4 for a small app?

Answer (score 0):

I found that Daphne fails silently when multi process are tried to be open on the same port and only one of them keeps alive.
https://github.com/django/daphne/issues/187

So I just duplicated the config and changed the ports and now all my processes are running fine.
[image]

As you can see no one exits now:
[image]